# Having trouble displaying value from dictionary off user input key

Tags: python

I have options done just need to know how to get the value from the user input key. All the ways I have tried returns a key error. Here is my code so far:

```
names= open('names.dat', 'r')
sonfather = names.read().split(',')

new_sonfather = []
for item in sonfather:
    new_sonfather.append(item.split(":"))
sonfather=new_sonfather

son_father_dictionary=dict(sonfather)
print son_father_dictionary


father_grandfather_dictionary=dict(son_father_dictionary)
print father_grandfather_dictionary

print son_father_dictionary.values()
print son_father_dictionary.keys()

print "0 - Quit"
print "1 - Find a Father"
print "2 - Find a Grandfather"
print "3 - Find a Son"
print "4 - Find a Grandson"
print "5 - List of names"

control = ""
while control != "quit":
    choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")
    if choice == 0:
        control = "quit"
        print("Thank you for using father/son finder")
    elif choice == 1:
        son = raw_input("Enter the name of the son: ")
        for son in son_father_dictionary:
            father=son_father_dictionary.get(son) 
            print father
            #I can return all the values in the dictionary, but I only need the 
             value of the key that is entered for son
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: ok. I have fixed my indention.

Answer (score 0):

```
control = True
while control:
    choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")
    control = int(sys.stdin.read(1))

    if choice == 1:
       son = raw_input("Enter the name of the son: ")
```

Comment: Don't understand this. I have it printing the user input 'son' with every set of value, but the value right after 'son' is all I need.

Comment: sorry, now it should work. it get into the loop the first time because control==True and keeps looping until control==0.

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to do. I have it going into the loop and gets the name from user during option 1, just need it to output the correct value when the key['son'] is entered.